# TypeScript error: TS2304:Cannot find name 'Date'

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to create a date object of javascript to store current date and time

```
let now:Date = new Date();
```

But the below line show error in my intellij as the below error:

```
TS2304:Cannot find name 'Date'.
```

I am guessing as Date is javascript object and new Date() is not available in typescript or in my project, its failing.

I am writing angularjs 1.5.9 in typescript, I dont thing is anything related to angularjs.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 16):

Step 1. Simply click on the version displayed in the footer of your visual studio code.

Step 2. Then choose Use Workspace version.

You will be good to go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275853/visual-studio-code-showing-error-cant-find-name-date/53278412

Answer (score -4):

try this`var today = new Date()`