# Visual studio code showing error "Can't find name Date"

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript

I am working on a basic Angular project with **Visual studio code(Version 1.19.2)** as my IDE.

The following piece of code is working fine but VSC doesn't seem to be happy about it.

It is showing error when i use `new Date()` or `JSON.stringify`

[image]

But the end results are correct and the console prints fine.

[image]

How to remove this error from **Visual studio code**?

---

**Update 1**

Here are my dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
```

Comment: what angular/typescript version? what does your tsconfig.json look like? are you using the angular cli?

Comment: Thanks for replying!! Updated the question.

Comment: try pressing `control` + `P` and type `> reload window`, it should fix the issue

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Doesn't work for me!!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan what about deleting node modules, deleting package-lock.json, and the doing a clean installation by doing `npm i` again?

Comment: Didn't work!!!!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan i can see your editor is using typescript@2.x.x. Can you upgrade it.

Comment: @Jai This worked perfectly. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My `Visual studio code` was using `Typescript v2.6.2`.

As mentioned by **@Jai** I updated the VSC's typescript version to match the Typescript version of my Angular project, which in my case was `Typescript v3.1.1`.

To update the typescript version

**Step 1.** Simply click on the version displayed in the footer of your visual studio code.

**Step 2.** Then choose *Use Workspace version*.

You will be good to go.

[image]

*PS: Special thanks to **@Jai**.*

Answer (score 0):

[image]

it works in a plain .js file for me in VSC.

I wonder if you have a TypeScript support extension, but somehow not a web or JavaScript support extension.

I would start with your VSC extensions and see if you can easily install one.