# JSON not found in Typescript application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2018

I have a simple Purchase class:

```
export class Purchase {

    customer!: Customer;
    
    shippingAddress!: Address;

    billingAddress!: Address;

    order!: Order;

    orderItems!: OrderItem[];
    
}
```

I have a checkout component which does the following:

```
// populate purchase - customer
purchase.customer = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['customer'].value;

// populate purchase - shipping address
purchase.shippingAddress = this.checkoutFormGroup.controls['shippingAddress'].value;
const shippingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.state));
const shippingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.country));
purchase.shippingAddress.state = shippingState.name;
purchase.shippingAddress.country = shippingCountry.name;
```

In this the below lines give the error `Cannot find name 'JSON'.ts(2304)`:

```
const shippingState: State = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.state));
const shippingCountry: Country = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purchase.shippingAddress.country));
```

I suspect the problem is that I've the following config in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
}
```

I tried changing `es2018` to `es5` but that didn't resolve my issue. Either way, surely there should be a way of doing this sort of thing with `es2018`. Can anybody tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you tried this in tsconfig.json?  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  }

Comment: Yes. It didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54061836/7836976) helped me fix my issue. The version was 4.5.something. It's now 4.2.2 and JSON is now found.